# Why Grayscale Image has Yellow components?

Tags: image-processing, rgba

I have following image

[image: JPEG image]

I wanted to convert it to the grayscale image with the following code.

```
class Pixel {
private:
    double c[4];
public:
    double  Luminance(void) const {
        // Return luminance
        return 0.30 * c[0] + 0.59 * c[1] + 0.11 * c[2];
    }

    void SetRed(double red) {
        // Set red component
        c[0] = red;
    }

    void SetGreen(double green) {
        // Set green component
        c[1] = green;
    }

    void SetBlue(double blue) {
        c[2] = blue;
    }

    void SetAlpha(double alpha) {
        // Set alpha component
        c[3] = alpha;
    }
};

class Image {
private:
    R2Pixel *pixels;
    int npixels;
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    void BlackAndWhite(void) {  
        // Replace each pixel with its luminance value
        // Put this in each channel,  so the result is grayscale
        for (int i = 0; i < this->npixels; i++) {
            auto luminance = pixels[i].Luminance();
            pixels[i].SetRed(luminance);
            pixels[i].SetGreen(luminance);
            pixels[i].SetRed(luminance);
        }
    }
};
```

There are more methods in both the classes which I kept out for the brevity. Main Methods of interests are Pixel::Luminance() and Image::BlackAndWhite(). The way Luminace() is calculated, I was expecting output to be grayscale Image. It is not the case though. In fact even if I set the value of each of Red, Green and Blue Channel to 1, image does not turn completely white. Instead it looks like something below

[image: Yellow Image after converting it to grayscale]

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any pointers will be appreciated.
Also, let me know if anyone think addition of more code is required for the cunderstanding of the question.

Thanks.

Comment: On the face of it, your code looks correct. I would be looking to the debugger and stop it at the point where the image is saved to disk and checking if the R/G/B values are equal...

Comment: Do you save your image direct to jpeg? What about converting RGB->YUV?

Comment: Thanks guys. @MarkSetchell You are right. The code is correct. I pulled the whole repo again. It worked with the same code. This was the only code I had changed though. Not sure what went wrong. Its working now :)